# Flutter ListView not updating after calling setstate

Tags: android, flutter

In my app, i created ListView list of widgets, but when i try to update it via list it doesn't update

Example Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ListTest> createState() => _ListTestState();
}

class _ListTestState extends State<ListTest> {
  List<Widget> widget_list = [
    ListTile(title: Text("1"),),
    ListTile(title: Text("2"),),
    ListTile(title: Text("3"),),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("List Length: "+widget_list.length.toString());
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("List Test"),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: widget_list,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.delete),
        onPressed: (){
          widget_list.clear();
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here when page is opened list length is 3, and when setState is called list length 0 is printed, but ListView doesn't get updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this problem by using ListView.builder instead of ListView. With the itemCount you give to ListView.builder, the number of elements of the list becomes dynamic. When there is a change in the number of elements, the list number is updated again.

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: widget_list.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return ListTile(
        title: widget_list[index],
      );
    },
  ),
```

Comment: thanks, it works, and also other answers,  widget_list = widget_list.toList(); also work.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what happens is that on rebuild the `ListView` sees that it is the same `List` object so it thinks that it doesn't need to be rebuild. To make it work correctly you can do

```
    onPressed: (){
      widget_list.clear();
      widget_list = widget_list.toList();
      setState(() {});
    },
```

That way it actually will be a different `List` object.

In the documentation of `ListView` it also says:

```
  /// Like other widgets in the framework, this widget expects that
  /// the [children] list will not be mutated after it has been passed in here.
```

Or you can also use a `ListView.builder` instead like in hakandl's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are **clearing** the list before **setState()** Again add widgets in that list "**widget_list**".

Do like this:-

```
 onPressed: (){
          widget_list.clear();
          widget_list = widget_list.toList();
          setState(() {});
    }
```